# Conway's Game of Life in Processing

Tags: java, processing, conways-game-of-life

So, the code is compiling and running perfectly. However, usually, Conway's Game of life stabilizes after some time, while this code keeps running indefinitely without ever getting a dead branch, and I'd love if anybody could help me figuring out why.

```
int[][] world;
int SCALE_FACTOR = 4;
float DENSITY = 0.1;

void setup() {
  size(500,500);
  world = new int[width/SCALE_FACTOR][height/SCALE_FACTOR];
  for(int i = 0; i < width/SCALE_FACTOR; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height/SCALE_FACTOR; j++) {
      int r = (int)random(100);
      world[i][j] = r % (int)(1/DENSITY) == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
  }
  frameRate(1);
  stroke(0, 255, 0);
}

void draw() {
  scale(SCALE_FACTOR);
  background(0);
  for(int i = 0; i < width/SCALE_FACTOR; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height/SCALE_FACTOR; j++) {
      if (world[i][j] == 1) point(i, j);
    }
  }
  lifeCycle();    
}

void lifeCycle() {
  int[][] newworld = new int[width/SCALE_FACTOR][height/SCALE_FACTOR];
  for(int i = 0; i < width/SCALE_FACTOR; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width/SCALE_FACTOR; j++) {
      if (world[i][j] == 1) {
        if (neighbours(i, j) == 3) {
          newworld[i][j] = 1;
        } else {
          newworld[i][j] = 0;
        }
      } else {
        if (neighbours(i, j) == 2 || neighbours(i, j) == 3) {
          newworld[i][j] = 1;
        } else {
          newworld[i][j] = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < width/SCALE_FACTOR; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height/SCALE_FACTOR; j++) {
      world[i][j] = newworld[i][j];
    }
  }
}

int neighbours(int x, int y) {
  int px = (x == width/SCALE_FACTOR - 1) ? 0 : (x+1);
  int py = (y == height/SCALE_FACTOR - 1) ? 0 : (y+1);
  int mx = (x == 0) ? (width/SCALE_FACTOR - 1) : (x-1);
  int my = (y == 0) ? (height/SCALE_FACTOR - 1) : (y-1);
  return world[mx][my] + world[mx][y] + world[mx][py]
    + world[x][my] + world[x][py]
    + world[px][my] + world[px][y] + world[px][py];
}
```

Comment: I'd say this is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: General strategy: unit test each piece of it.  It looks like your branches of the if-statement are backward when looking at if a current cell is alive/dead or not.  That is, a dead cell should become alive with three neighbours, and a live cell should stay alive with 2/3 neighbours.

Comment: Will keep it in mind, first time coming here, thanks Andrew

Comment: Separate the problematic code and ask again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this looks wrong to start with:

```
for (int j = 0; j < width/SCALE_FACTOR; j++) {
```

Surely that should be `height`.

Next up: currently your logic says, "If the square was alive before, it's only alive in the next round if it's got three neighbours; if it was dead before, it's alive in the next round if it's got two or three neighbours." That's the wrong way round. It takes three live neighbours to *create* life, but only two or three neighbours to *sustain* life.

That's all I can immediately see that's wrong with it, but tips on diagnosing the problem:

- I'd strongly suggest keeping `width` and `height` in *game* terms rather than pixel sizes, which I assume is what `SCALE_FACTOR` is meant to be. Scale the units *up* when drawing, but keep all your logic in terms of the actual grid elements.
- If you isolate the UI from the "business logic" you can easily unit test it.
- When you're using a UI to display the board, you might want to give it a "manual advance" mode so you can see exactly what's going on more easily.

Comment: Oh that was definitely it, I got the logic wrong from the actual game. Thanks for the useful suggestions though, will keep them in mind!